Drawing on an image in Angular
I am trying to submit a form where the user would have the option to draw on an image, download it, and submit it along with the form.
However, I can't seem to find the correct library to use. The only one I can find is deprecated (ngx-image-drawing).

Deprecated does not mean removed

Why use a library ? Just use a canvas with a few lines of Javascript to allow drawing on it ? Would be both a good exercise, and another library you wouldn't have to depend on

I know, but is it still okay to use? I would ideally like to use something that is constantly being developed and upgraded. Also, thanks for responding..

I like your comment about not depending on a library, I was just wondering if there was something already ready to use.  @MGX

You can also look on Angular Three
